# for loop not suitable?

Tags: php

I have created a for loop.
I am trying to loop through lots of members and create a row for each member in a table.

It's looping through too many times.
Is it the right type of loop to use?

```
        <?php
    for ($i = 1; $i = count($u); $i++) 
    {
        ?>
        <tr>
                <?php
                    echo "<td>$i</td>";
                ?>

                <?php
                foreach ($u as $username)
                {
                    echo "<td>$username</td>";
                }
                ?>
                <?php
                foreach ($p as $points)
                {
                    echo "<td>$points</td>";
                }
                ?>
        </tr>
        <?
    }
    ?>
```

$u and $p are arrays.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can shorten it a bit and remove the inner loops:

```
<php
 for ($i = 1; $i <= count($u); $i++) 
 {
   echo '<tr>';
   echo "<td>$i</td>";
   echo "<td>$u[$i]</td>";
   echo "<td>$p[$i]</td>";
   echo '</tr>';
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: The variables inside the loop would need to be inside <?php ?> tags too.

Comment: I just did something similar to this, thanks bud.
Nice to know im getting the right ideas.

Answer (score 2):

`$i = count($u)` in the loop is what's causing the problem:

```
for ($i = 1; $i = count($u); $i++)
```

On every iteration of the loop, you're assigning `count($u)` to `$i` using a single `=`.  Should be

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= count($u); $i++)
```

or

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($u); $i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$count = count($u);
for ($i = 1; $i < $count; $i++) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $i . '</td>';
    foreach ($u as $username) {
        echo '<td>' . $username . '</td>';
    }
    foreach ($p as $points) {
        echo '<td>' . $points . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
?>
```

You should count $u before you loop it.